# How to show the image by the the image name in Xcode 5

Tags: objective-c, image

I want to see the image when I click on it is name, while i press command button :

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.png"]
```

but I get "symbol not found"... How can I do that?
edit:
this what Xcode show me when I press on "@"Background.png" ...

[image]

Comment: Could you provide more code and full compiler error details?

Comment: no i don't have any error, I just want to see the background.png image,instead of searching it between all my images....

Comment: Could you provide more info where do you want to see image and where do you see "symbol not found" message? It's difficult to analyse problem without more details.

Comment: yes of course, I add the image that Xcode show me when I press on "Background.png", I just want from Xcode to open the image background.png that's all !!

Comment: Zev Eisenberg has provided correct answer for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you command-clicking on `@"Background.png"`? That will not work in the current version of Xcode. It can’t take you to the source image - Command-clicking works only for symbols such as variables and classes. It’s a good idea for a feature, though, so you should probably [file a feedback](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/). However, you may want to look at the [KSImageNamed-Xcode](https://github.com/ksuther/KSImageNamed-Xcode) plugin, which you can install via [Alcatraz](http://alcatraz.io).